# How to unittest jinja2?

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-app-engine, jinja2

I've been using `webtest` for unit testing, but that only takes me so far when using templating with google app engine.

The only related info I found was [how to unittest the template variables passed to jinja2 template from webapp2 request handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527166/how-to-unittest-the-template-variables-passed-to-jinja2-template-from-webapp2-re)

However, I found it hard to digest.

The web lacks info on this as well.

A snippet of my code in one of my handlers is:

```
template_values = {
        "message": "Ello Mate",
        "errors": self.error_message,
        "stats" : self.statuses
    }
template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

Is there a good way to check the template values without just printing out the response?

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer it's required to use a mock for BaseHandler.render_template to check the template values instead of printing the HTML response. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock is the framework which is now the default in Python 3 (you can use this in Python 2  via pip). Unfortunately I don't have a complete example right now but I may update this question later.

Answer (score 0):

Adam is right; you could mock it, and that might suit your needs perfectly. Alternatively, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406034/unittest-jinja2-and-webapp2-template-not-found) has information on getting Jinja2 working without mocking it. Then you could use [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) to look for the `template_values` in the HTML response (give their html elements unique id's to make that easier).